# dual booted UEFI Ubuntu in Legacy Windows. Now none of them boots properly

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

I am a complete beginner and later understood that I did a great mistake.

I booted UEFI Ubuntu with Legacy Windows. Now even Ubuntu does not boot properly. Everytime I have to enter this codes in the GNU GRUB to enter into Ubuntu.

```
grub> set root=(hd0,1)
grub> linux /vmlinuz-4.4.0-38-generic 
grub> initrd /initrd.img-4.4.0-38-generic
grub> boot
```

Windows cannot be accessed anyhow. It doesn't even come up in update-grub and os-prober returns nothing. Any idea on what to do?

Comment: For a long time Windows has required UEFI not Bios. Please put in details of your Windows version and Ubuntu version. How did you install bot OSs? Was Windows there and you have now added Ubuntu? If you enter the compuiter's Bios settings (eg f2 / f10 / f12 / Del), can you select Legacy and then the Windows partition to boot from directly? If you only occasionally use one of the OSs that might be your best option, but if you want easy access to both I think you'll need to reinstall so they are both EFI.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a bit more detail.

Is this two hard disk or one drive with multiple partitions.  Show ouputs of lsblk (display tree of disks / partitions)  And for Windows partition display the details of the partition and labels / flags.

Ex: My Ubuntu 22.04 VM has a single Virtual Drive so not very interesting

nerd@lt:/$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTSnerd@lt:/$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                       7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1                       7:1    0 219.2M  1 loop /snap/code/97
<snip: loop devices>
loop24                      7:24   0 105.5M  1 loop /snap/slack/64
sda                         8:0    0    60G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                      8:2    0     2G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0  46.9G  0 part
└─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  46.9G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

This shows One Drive three partitions

nerd@lt:/$ sudo parted /dev/sda
[sudo] password for nerd:
GNU Parted 3.4
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p
Model: Msft Virtual Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 64.4GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
1      1049kB  1128MB  1127MB  fat32              boot, esp
2      1128MB  3276MB  2147MB  ext4
3      3276MB  53.7GB  50.4GB

(parted) q

Last would be to show current grub boot structure.  YOu are booting enough to get to grub.. which is good... so its now just a matter of formatting your boot into the various OS images (A$$uming they are still there :P.

sudo nano /etc/default/grub

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

Above is very basic, so post what you have and how it matches what you type in.

Also look at some other grub basic postings on how to configure things: https://www.howtogeek.com/196655/how-to-configure-the-grub2-boot-loaders-settings/